# How to remove Recent use applications android

Tags: java, android

I want to kill background process but how to remove recent task from background with kill process?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your manifest file write this for particular activity.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: thanks, but it is only for excluding my own application. i am asking about to remove other apps from recent

Comment: How to remove other apps from background.

Comment: You can't. You need to have access to Root